# How to change avatar in Skype?

Tags: skype

I've installed Skype on my Ubuntu by doing this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install skype
```

I've registered my account. And I want to change my avatar. But i don't know how :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Steps:

1. Open Skype
2. Click on your username
3. Click on the image.
4. Select a new one!
5. Done!

Comment: Gotta love UIs without text :-s